# Android HTML Parsing: Trigger a onclick event programatically

Tags: javascript, android, html, parsing, onchange

I have a Url/HTML page containing a Table of fields. Two of the input fields are dropdown/select.

When a particular element in the 1st dropdown is selected manually then the second dropdown list is populated with corresponding entries. There is a javascript written in `onchange` of the 1st select/dropdown field which is actually triggered on selection.

How can I do this programmatically? I want the html page which is formed after selecting the item in 1st dropdown list so i can parse it and get elements in 2nd dropdown list.

The 1st list is like this. On selecting any item the new list is formed in he next select tag

```
<select name="list1" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__funtion1(\'list1\',\'\')', 0)" id="list1" tabindex="3" style="width:173px;">
  <option value="0">[Please select]</option>
  <option value="1">Aaaaa</option>
  <option value="2">bbbbbb</option>
  <option value="3">ccccc</option>
</select>
```

I somehow want the resulting page so that i can parse it and get the elements in the new list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the resulting page, just get the options from the 2nd select:

```
list2.options[i];  

list2.options[i].text; // if you need the text
```

UPDATE:
In this case simply call directly the `onchange event handler __funtion1('list1','') (you can call a 
javascript function from the Android activity)` to populate the 2nd select and then you're good to go

Comment: Mate, thats what my qurestion is...how can i call that javascript from android programatically :/ PS:Mods sorry if am not able to reply on the right place

Comment: Load the page into a WebView then:
`code`
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
...
webView.loadUrl("javascript:__funtion1('list1','');");
`code`